# Android splash screen crashes

Tags: android

My application shows a splash screen at launch. The screen will display for 3 seconds. While it is being displayed, the app will download json from the server. Either when 3 minutes is up or when the download is finished (whichever takes longer), the main screen will be loaded. The following code shows how this is achieved.

```
    if (isNetworkConnected()) {
        networkConnected = true;
    } else {
        networkConnected = false;
        toast(R.string.no_internet_connection);
    }

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            timeIsUp = true;
            if (syncDone || !networkConnected)
                loadHomeActivity();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

    Callback<DenkoModel> callback = new Callback<DenkoModel>() {
        @Override
        public void success(DenkoModel denkoModel, Response response) {
            toast(R.string.server_connection_successful);
            syncDone = true;

            denkoStationService.updateDatabaseWithDenkoModel(denkoModel);

            if (timeIsUp)
                loadHomeActivity();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            toast(R.string.server_connection_failed);
            syncDone = true;
            if (timeIsUp)
                loadHomeActivity();
        }
    };

    denkoStationService.fetchDenkoModel(denkoStationService.fetchDenkoLastDataState(), callback);
```

The code works fine on the emulator but when I test it on a real device, the application crashes. My guess is that thread issues are causing the application to crash but all events are taking place on the main thread.

What might be causing application crashes and how can I solved the problem?

Edit: My logcat output

```
04-18 11:43:06.810  11612-11612/? W/SignalStrength﹕ getLevel=2
04-18 11:43:07.230      429-446/? I/PackageManager﹕ Removing non-system package:org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.denko
04-18 11:43:07.390      429-472/? E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1086K, 42% free 17256K/29447K, paused 4ms+25ms, total 120ms
04-18 11:43:08.350      429-472/? I/PackageManager﹕ Updating external media status from unmounted to unmounted


04-18 11:43:08.370  10350-10364/? I/k9﹕ storage path "/storage/sdcard0" unmounting
04-18 11:43:08.410      429-446/? I/PackageManager﹕ Running dexopt on: org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.denko
04-18 11:43:08.890      429-503/? E/WifiHW﹕ wifi_send_command : SIGNAL_POLL ; interface index=0;
04-18 11:43:09.690  10350-10364/? I/k9﹕ storage path "/storage/sdcard0" unmounted
04-18 11:43:10.040      429-457/? W/lights﹕ TP Button Light current value is 255


04-18 11:43:23.400  11913-11929/? I/PushLogAC2313﹕ [Thread-6813-6813]the pkgName:org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.denko, localPkgName:com.huawei.android.pushagent(pushagent/null:-1)


04-18 11:43:24.380  24178-24178/? I/AppAddOrRemoveListener﹕ org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.denko uninstalled
04-18 11:43:24.460      429-457/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed 


04-18 11:43:24.460      429-457/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.denko/.activity.SplashScreenActivity: +2s119ms
04-18 11:43:24.470  11967-11967/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-18 11:43:24.550  11967-11967/? W/dalvikvm﹕ Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/hwframework.jar'


04-18 11:43:29.490  10526-11790/? W/AmazonAppstore.AppManagerAndroidPackageDelegate﹕ Unable to determine asin for package org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.denko.  Skipping metadata update.


[ReceiverDispatcher-6814]responseAddPackage pkgName= org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.denko(pushagent/null:-1)
04-18 11:43:30.360  11913-11942/? I/PushLogAC2313﹕ [ReceiverDispatcher-6814]PushState get action :android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED(pushagent/null:-1)


04-18 11:43:32.480  24178-24178/? I/AppAddOrRemoveListener﹕ org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.denko installed
04-18 11:43:32.890  12113-12113/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)


04-18 11:43:34.480  10526-11790/? W/AmazonAppstore.AppManagerAndroidPackageDelegate﹕ Unable to determine asin for package org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.denko.  Skipping metadata update.
04-18 11:43:34.570  12159-12159/? W/System.err﹕ Invalid int: ""
04-18 11:43:34.590  12159-12159/? W/ExpressLog﹕ can't find sdcard for log store.
04-18 11:43:34.640  12159-12159/? I/UpdateManager﹕ 


04-18 11:43:34.950  24178-24178/? I/AppAddOrRemoveListener﹕ org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.denko replaced
04-18 11:43:34.990     429-3345/? E/LocSvc_api_rpc_glue﹕ V/proc: 1  prog: 3100008c  vers: 50001
```

Edit:

`DenkoApplication.java`

```
public class DenkoApplication extends Application {

    private static Context initialContext;
    private static SQLiteDatabase database;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        initialContext = getApplicationContext();
        setupDb();
        setupLanguage();
        registerLocationListener();
    }

    private void setupDb() {
        DenkoDbHelper helper = new DenkoDbHelper(initialContext, "denko-stations-db", null);
        database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return initialContext;
    }

    public static SQLiteDatabase getDatabase() {
        return database;
    }

    private void setupLanguage() {
        setLocale(readLanguage());
    }

    private void setLocale(String lang) {
        Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    }

    private void registerLocationListener() {
        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener mlocListener = new DenkoLocationListener();
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
        DenkoLocationListener.isGpsEnabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }

    private SharedPreferences obtainSharedPreferences() {
        return getSharedPreferences("org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.denko", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    private String readLanguage() {
        return obtainSharedPreferences().getString("org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.denko.language", "en");
    }
}
```

`SplashScreenActivity.java`

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @InjectView(R.id.imgLogo)
    ImageView logoImage;

    @InjectView(R.id.welcomeText)
    TextView welcomeText;

    boolean timeIsUp;
    boolean syncDone;
    boolean networkConnected;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        DenkoStationComponent component = DaggerDenkoStationComponent.builder().denkoStationModule(new DenkoStationModule()).build();
        final DenkoStationService denkoStationService = component.provideDenkoStationService();

        if (isNetworkConnected()) {
            networkConnected = true;
        } else {
            networkConnected = false;
            toast(R.string.no_internet_connection);
        }

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                timeIsUp = true;
                if (syncDone || !networkConnected)
                    loadHomeActivity();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

        Callback<DenkoModel> callback = new Callback<DenkoModel>() {
            @Override
            public void success(DenkoModel denkoModel, Response response) {
                toast(R.string.server_connection_successful);
                syncDone = true;

                denkoStationService.updateDatabaseWithDenkoModel(denkoModel);

                if (timeIsUp)
                    loadHomeActivity();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                toast(R.string.server_connection_failed);
                syncDone = true;
                if (timeIsUp)
                    loadHomeActivity();
            }
        };

        denkoStationService.fetchDenkoModel(denkoStationService.fetchDenkoLastDataState(), callback);
    }

    private void loadHomeActivity() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        finish();
    }

    private SharedPreferences obtainSharedPreferences() {
        return getSharedPreferences("org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.denko", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    private String readLanguage() {
        return obtainSharedPreferences().getString("org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.denko.language", "en");
    }

    private void writeLanguage(String language) {
        obtainSharedPreferences().edit().putString("org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.denko.language", language).apply();
    }

    public void toast(int textId) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_text);
        text.setText(getResources().getString(textId));

        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    private ListView mDrawerList;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private String[] items;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menus);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

        DenkoMenuArrayAdapter adapter = new DenkoMenuArrayAdapter(this, items);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /* Called when drawer is closed */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                //Put your code here
            }

            /* Called when a drawer is opened */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                //Put your code here
            }
        };

        /* Setting DrawerToggle on DrawerLayout */
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                displayView(position);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        });
        updateFragment();
    }

    public void updateFragment() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        MainViewFragment rFragment = new MainViewFragment();

        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, rFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new MainViewFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new StationViewFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new MapViewFragment();
                break;
            /*case 3:
                fragment = new CommunityFragment();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new PagesFragment();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
                break;*/

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
}
```

Comment: Logcat has been included in the question.

Comment: It's not an `AsyncTask` problem. Retrofit will download the json and when it has received the data and finished decoding, it will call the callback so the problem isn't as simple as network on main thread. Also real devices allow suck code to run. Only debugging environments don't allow it.

Comment: @SandahAung your given log cat output doesn;t contain Errors.

Comment: That's the reason I can't figure out my problem too. It doesn't produce any errors.

Comment: please post your splash class and the main class that it leads to, without posting those two we can't really understand the whole problem.
help us to help you

Answer (score 3):

Try This code, It worked for me.

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
// Splash screen timer
private Handler splashHandler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    };
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Intent brain = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(brain);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    };
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    if (isNetworkAvailable())
        splashHandler.postDelayed(r, 3000);
    else {
        //splashHandler.postDelayed(r, 3000);
        //Notify user they aren't connected
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You aren't connected to the internet.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        splashHandler.postDelayed(r, 3000);
        //close the app
        //finish();
    }
}

public void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onResume();
}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}
}
```